# MESI protocol. Write with cache miss, but cache line copy exists on another CPU. Why needs fetch from main memory?

Tags: caching, cpu-cache, mesi

According to this [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#/media/File:MESI_protocol_activity_diagram.png) in case of write cache miss with copy in another CPU cache (for example *Shared*/*Exclusive* state). The steps are:

**1.** Snooping cores (with cache line copy) sets state to *Invalid*.

**2.** Current cache stores fresh main memory value.

Why one of the snooping cores can't put its cache line value on the bus at first? And then go to *Invalid* state. The same algorithm is used in read miss with existing copy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right in that it's pretty silly to go fetch a line from memory when you already have it right next to you, but this diagram describes the minimal requirement for *functional correctness* of the coherence protocol (i.e. what must be done to avoid coherence bugs), and that only dictates snooping the data out for modified lines since that's the only correct copy. What you describe is a possible optimization, and some systems indeed behave that way.

However, keep in mind that most systems today employ a shared cache as well (L2 or L3, sometimes even beyond that), and this is often inclusive (with regards to all lines that exist in all cores). In such systems, there's no real need to go all the way to memory, since having the line in another core means it's also in the shared cache, and after invalidation the requesting core can obtain it from there. Your proposal is therefore relevant only for systems with no shared cache, or with a cache that is not strictly inclusive.